# I don't have permission to delete objects with the Facebook SDK

Tags: python, facebook, permissions, sdk, http-delete

I'm trying to implement a Python script to retrieve my posts and that is able to delete some of them. When retrieving everything seems to work good, but when I call the `delete_object` method, it says I don't have permissions.

I have my user access token and from the dashboard I gave all the permissions. Then from my Facebook profile I agreed for my app to perform all the actions.

Here's the simple function that takes in a list of post IDs as input:

```py
fb = facebook.GraphAPI(token, version="3.1")
my_profile = fb.get_object('me')
my_id = my_profile["id"]

def delete_posts(posts):
    for i in range(len(posts)):
        fb.delete_object(posts[i])
```

And here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Download/FBHandler/main.py", line 159, in <module>
    fb.delete_object(id)
  File "D:\Download\FBHandler\venv\lib\site-packages\facebook\__init__.py", line 197, in delete_object
    return self.request("{0}/{1}".format(self.version, id), method="DELETE")
  File "D:\Download\FBHandler\venv\lib\site-packages\facebook\__init__.py", line 299, in request
    raise GraphAPIError(result)
facebook.GraphAPIError: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/post#deleting

> **An app can delete any post it published**, or a page-management app can delete a Post published to a Page that the app manages.

If the post was not created by that App, you cannot delete it.

Comment: I missed this particular. Thanks!